How can I find accuracy in RBF kernal SVM?
I am trying to implement human detection using SVM. I am using HOG feature extraction and then applying SVM on it. When I apply linear SVM I will get score of an image but in RBF kernal SVM I only get 0 and 1. Is there anyway i can get score of a detection? How can i see coefficients of RBF kernal like linear SVM?
I tried SVM libraries which are provided by python.


Can you be more specific about which libraries you're using? There are multiple SVM libraries. 2) Can you provide the code for your existing approach?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.


[...] in RBF kernal SVM I only get 0 and 1. Is there anyway i can get score of a detection?

One way of getting a score is to use the .decision_function(X) method of the SVC. The larger it is, the further away the point is from the decision plane (the sign indicates the class). However, it is an unbounded value that can be arbitrarily large.
A second option is to set SVC(probability=True, ...), which gives you access to a probability score (by default probability is False). It will take longer to run .fit(). You can then get the probabilities using the .predict_proba(X) method.

How can i see coefficients of RBF kernal like linear SVM?

You can't do this directly with SVC(kernel='rbf'). However, you can approximate the RBF feature space using kernel_approximation.RBFSampler or kernel_approximation.Nystroem, and then pipeline that into a LinearSVC (or any of SGDClassifer(loss='hinge'); SVC(kernel='linear')). That would allow you to access the coefficients for the approximated RBF space, as shown below.
from sklearn.kernel_approximation import Nystroem, RBFSampler
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

#np.random.seed(0) #makes example reproducible

rbf_svc_approx = make_pipeline(
    Nystroem(kernel='rbf', n_components=100, n_jobs=-1),
    LinearSVC(),
)

#Access coefficients corresponding to the 100-dimensional RBF feature space
rbf_coeffs = rbf_svc_approx['linearsvc'].coef_

You might find some details here of interest.
